# Find linux soft link

Tags: symbolic-link

We have an ExpressionEngine installation. The CSS templates are stored in a directory called /na_cms/expressionengine/templates/default_site/c.group

When EE parses these out, the path becomes /css/c

EE does not change the path, I'm reckoning it is a symbolic link. How can I find where that is setup?

Also, Javascript files are in the j.group directory but the links parse out to /j

It is not being done in .htaccess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I don't misunderstand the question, try `ls -al /na_cms`, then `ls -al /na_cms/expressionengine`, then... well, you get the idea.  That's what I tend to do, anyway!

Comment: going all the way up the chain, I don't see any link listings.

Comment: OK, then you know that your earlier hypothesis - that it's a symbolic link - is wrong.